# Java equivalent of cin (C++)

Tags: java, c++

how would you code this in Java?

```
char c;
int n;
cin >> c >> n;
```

So that I can get this kind of inputs:

```
X123123
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) with [`System.in`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in).  E.g.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
char c = s.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
int n = s.nextInt();
```

Comment: Yes, but how to get a char and an int on the same line?

Comment: @Ivan: I've just added links to the docs, should help. (The third example, for instance; just ignore the delimiter bit.)

Comment: @Ivan, don't try to emulate C++ in Java. Writing idiomatic Java code makes you're easier to grok for Java programmers.